# Show all not empty tables, with a especific column, postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

The problem is the following, how through a query in postgresl/pgadmin I can get all the tables with a specific column and that this column is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to is the following.

```
SELECT relname, n_tup_ins
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE relname IN (
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE column_name = 'company_id' AND table_schema = 'public' AND table_schema = 'company_id'.
    AND table_schema = 'public'
)
ORDER BY n_tup_ins DESC
```

Where company_id is the column I was looking for.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't see this working with `AND` as any single `column_name`/`table_name` would have to have `table_schema` equal to all the schemas for a  `table_name`/`column_name` combination. I think you are looking for `OR`.

Comment: Also be aware  that `pg_stat_all_tables` is not always up to date, especially if you are working in a transaction. See [Statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) *28.2.2. Viewing Statistics*

Comment: Finally `n_tup_ins` is the cumulative total of tuples(rows)  inserted since the table was created or the statistics where reset. So: 1) It is a row count not a column data count.  2) Those tuples may not  exist any more.

Comment: Wow Adrian, thanks you for all the information, i really didn't know those details and I was just looking for a way to find all the tables that had at least one row of a certain column.
Thank you very much!

Comment: The point is your answer is not actually an answer to your question. You should delete it.